# Undefined variable errors that disappear, should I worry about them?

Tags: 7, commerce, debugging

I get these when I first login to my admin account:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: total in include() (line 19 of C:\WAMP\apache2\htdocs\apricity\sites\all\themes\apricity\templates\page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: base_url in eval() (line 17 of C:\WAMP\apache2\htdocs\apricity\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
```

$total is a variable I'm using in page.tpl for the commerce module:

```
  <?php
  global $user;
  $quantity = 0;
  $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
  if ($order) {
      $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
      $line_items = $wrapper->commerce_line_items;
      $quantity = commerce_line_items_quantity($line_items, commerce_product_line_item_types());
      $total = commerce_line_items_total($line_items);
      $currency = commerce_currency_load($total['currency_code']);
  }
  ?>
```

and it works great. $base_url I have in settings.php like usual. What's strange is if I refresh the page the errors disappear. Should I worry about them?

Comment: as a test, login as admin, clear the cache, logout and then login immediately - does it show? do you allow anonymous users to create orders?

Comment: @Geoff it does show. It shows every time I login no matter how long ago I cleared cache. And yes I do allow anonymous users to create orders.

Comment: I would suspect $total isnt being assigned properly or is being assigned null. Try outputting $total right after it is assigned with dpm() or print_r to see if it shows anything on the first page load